# High chart on click event listening

Tags: highcharts

I am creating my high chart object from a json_encoded array passed in from a data id on the containing div.

```
$('div.filter_pie_chart').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).highcharts($(this).data("params"));
    });
```

I would like to listen for click events of a pie chart using the following notation. Is this possible?

```
$(document).on('click','.high_chart_point_object', function (event) {
       return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this [documentation link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) is what you need.

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-click/).

```
$(function () {
    // create the chart
    var mychart = $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    alert ('x: '+ event.xAxis[0].value +', y: '+
                          event.yAxis[0].value);
                }
            }        
        },
        xAxis: {
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

And I think these lines should work too (not tested, but it is similar to your notation) :

```
$('.high_chart_point_object').highcharts({
  chart: {
    events: {
      click: function(event) {
        return false;
      }
    }        
  }
});
```

If you want to change options dynamically, here is the solution :

```
var options = mychart.options;
options.chart.events.click = function () {alert('do what you want')};
mychart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Here is another [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42SvV/1/).

Comment: I want to add the event handler after creating the High Charts object. Your example passes them all in at the same time.

Comment: You've got your solution. ;) But explain more what you want next time. We cannot help you if your informations are poor. And I don't really understand why you want to add the event handler afer creating the chart... ??

Comment: My application allows the user to extend the functionality after creation. So I create the bare bones graph then give them the ability enter css or jquery to enhance the graph. Your solution doesn't use jquery to change the options.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want. I think you have everything you need in my post, so goodbye! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should possible in three ways:

- one is to use `plotOpttions.pie.point.events.click` ant there call function you need to. [Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events).
- another one is to `Element.on()` function from Highcharts after digging for DOM elements - it's the same as using `$().on()`, [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.on()).
- if you really need that `$().on()`, you can use is on `point.element`, sample for you: http://jsfiddle.net/UWZAe/

And code for third case:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var chart = this,
                    pie = chart.series[0],
                    pieData = pie.data,
                    dLen = pieData.length;

                for(var i = 0; i < dLen; i++){
                    var slice = pieData[i];

                    console.log(slice, $(slice.graphic)); 
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```